# Set CET timezone with toISOString()

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, timestamp

How do I change the MYSQL timestamp date to the JS date using toISOString () and setting the time-zone to CET?
This is what I use and it returns the following format "2021-02-251 15:27:20" which is what I want, only the time should be +1 hour "2021-02-251 16:27:20 ":

```
registration_date_customer.toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '')
```

The time on the database is correct (16:27:20).
Does anyone know how to set the CET time-zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Date.localeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to format in the correct timeZone, the IANA timezone "Europe/Paris" is equivalent to CET. Using the "sv" locale will result in an ISO formatted string (Sweden uses ISO date formatting).

```js
const registration_date_customer = new Date("2021-02-25 15:27:20Z");
console.log(registration_date_customer.toLocaleString("sv", { timeZone: "Europe/Paris"}));
```